# Color string along with bracket if its value is greater than 0 in vba

Tags: excel, vba

With below code I'm trying to color sting along with bracket when its value is > 0. But it's not working as expected. The color is not applied correctly.

```vb
Sub sdasd()
    Dim LArray() As String
    Dim sss() As String
    For Each cell In Range("Z7:AB16")
    LArray = Split(cell.Value, "(")
    sss = Split(LArray(1), ")")
    sFind = sss(0)
    If sFind > 0 Then
        iLen = Len(sFind)
        IFind = InStr(cell.Value, sFind)
        cell.Characters(IFind, iLen).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Another approach, still no luck

```
Sub sdasd()
Dim LArray() As String
Dim sss() As String
Dim st As Integer
For Each cell In Range("Z7:AB16")

Data = cell.Value
    LArray = Split(cell.Value, "(")
    sss = Split(LArray(1), ")")
    sFind = sss(0)
    If sFind > 0 Then
        iLen = Len(sFind)
        st = Len(Data) - (Len(LArray(1)) + 1)
        cell.Characters(st, iLen).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `IFind = InStr(cell.Value, sFind)` - this finds the first occurrence of the number in question.

Comment: If there is text instead of number outside brackets it's working fine e.g. test(2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic line is `IFind = InStr(cell.Value, sFind)`.

`InStr` finds the *first* occurrence of `sFind`, which may not be the number inside the parentheses but rather an earlier instance.

Although I would approach this differently, an easy fix might be to use the position of the `(` as the *start* parameter of `InStr`.

```
Dim pos as Long
pos = InStr(cell.Value, "(")
IFind = InStr(pos, cell.Value, sFind)
```

Comment: Works fine, thank you! Can't we apply when cell has formula?

Comment: No - you cannot change the color when the cell has a formula.